# How to run handler functions sequentially

Tags: go, backend

I have a handler function for an endpoint. The handler takes a very long time to return a response, consists a lot of processing. I do not want other incoming requests to run concurrently but instead wait for the previous one to finish! Tried implementing waitGroups, check the code! Every time for a new request a new instance of wait group is created and it starts running concurrently instead of waiting for the older one to complete. Is my wait group approach incorrect?

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func Handler(c *gin.Context) {
  // some stuff that takes ~10-15 seconds, can't be run concurrently
  // If a second request comes put it in a queue and execute it only once this is done
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        //some processing happens
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "Hello!"})
}
router.POST("/doSomething", Handler)
```

Comment: First, this sounds like a broken requirement. Your entire HTTP server should not hang while serving one client.

Comment: I'm not sure how a WaitGroup could possibly be a solution to this; if you want one thing to do something at any given time, that's a Mutex. A WaitGroup is for waiting for many things doing something at the same time to all finish.

Comment: What probably makes more sense is one of the following: 1) If the request is already happening, return a 429 or similar error, indicating that it can't be run again at the same time. 2) Put it into a queue, and return a 201 immediately.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding waitgroups. Your waitgroup is waiting for a single process to complete, before returning a result--exactly as it would if you didn't use a goroutine at all. As mentioned in the answer below, a mutex is the proper tool for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, this looks like a broken requirement. However if you really want to have one instance of the function running, you can use a mutex:

```
var lock sync.Mutex
func Handler(c *gin.Context) {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
     // Process
}
```